# WebLogic Toplink (its xml parser?) configuration issue

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, toplink

I have a web application (war packaged) with toplink.jar and xmlparserv2.jar files under WEB-INF\lib. The problem is that I get

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/schema/XSDElement
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at oracle.toplink.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.newInstanceFromClass(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:335)
    at oracle.toplink.platform.xml.XMLPlatformFactory.getXMLPlatform(XMLPlatformFactory.java:95)
```

I don't understand it because xmlparserv2.jar contains `oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDElement` class - so it should be on classpath. 
My WebLogic version is 10.3.2.0, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this more helpful:

http://appsonlinedba.blogspot.com/2011/05/bi-publisher-scheduler-configurations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line in Arguments in Server Start tab in WebLogic admin console

```
-Dtoplink.xml.platform=oracle.toplink.platform.xml.jaxp.JAXPPlatform
```

Source: https://community.oracle.com/message/2988932?tstart=44

Comment: @ekad where is  "Server Start tab in WebLogic admin console" located? i am unable to find this, i have the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/schema/XSDBuilder` and i read somewhere that your solution is the same fix, but i cant find it.

Comment: @ekad i found it, and added the argument, but i still have the same error